# Can't hide MarkerWithLabel on Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using this code to display set and display multiple markers:

```
MarkerStore[res[i].id].setIcon(icon);
```

Then I place the marker with:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat,res[i].position.long),
                        title:'',
                        map:map,
                        icon: icon, 
});
```

And hide it (if needed) with:

```
MarkerStore[res[i].id].setVisible(true);
```

This works perfectly. So, now I want to add labels with the `MarkerWithLabel` option. I change the code to

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat,res[i].position.long),
                        labelContent: markerLabel,
                        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 12),
                        labelClass: "my-custom-class-for-label",
                        labelInBackground: true,
                        title:'',
                        map:map,
                        icon: icon,
});
```

Suddenly, it doesn't work anymore. It doesn't hide anything but displays all markers on the map, even if they should be hidden. What am I doing wrong? Is this a problem with the `MarkerWithLabel` feature?

Comment: Just so I'm clear: your `MarkerWithLabel` creates the markers correctly, the only problem is that your `...setVisible()` code is not correctly hiding them?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.